# QR Code Return Type Extraction in Android using ZXing

Tags: android, qr-code

I have an app that can successfully retrive the data returned by a QR Code via sending an intent to the Barcode Scanner App made by ZXing.

However, I want to make the app better by being able to decipher if the format of the QR Code is a phone number. Is it possible to also obtain the format of the QR Code (ie URL, SMS, Phone number, text)?

I need this because I don't want loopholes like people creating their own QR Codes to scan. The QR Codes I created for a system I was asked to create has the phone number format. People may be able to do counterfeit QR Codes that have Text as the format. I want the app to be able to differentiate between the formats so this can be avoided. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really mean the barcode format, this is also returned in the `Intent`. Look at extra `SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT` which will have a String like "QR_CODE". These are names of enum values in `BarcodeFormat`.

If you mean you want to parse the result of the scan like Barcode Scanner does, use the `ResultParser` class from `core/`.

I don't see how any of this prevents making up your own barcode though.

Comment: Hello sir! I have tried using the SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT and it did return QR_CODE which I expected since I sent the intent to scan a QR_CODE. However, I noticed that when it finds a QR Code, it says below of the scanner: "Found Phone Number" or "Found Plain Text". Are there ways to extract those? Thank you.

Comment: Yes and I just found the ResultParser class in the com.google.zxing.client.result package. My bad. Thank you so much!

Comment: Sorry, but how exactly do I use the ResultParser class from my app? Obviously I can't use it via the intent class. Do I do it like: 'Class<ResultParser> format = ResultParser.class'? But then again I can't access the methods and variables ResultParser has via 'format.method' or 'format.variable'. I'm a bit confused on how to go about with this.

Comment: No you import the code from core/ and use it in your app project. See how it is used in android/

Comment: Okay I managed to do just that and I initialized a Result Object `result` and a ResultParser Object `format` properly. Now the things is I don't know the proper syntax for `Result result = ;` so that when I use `format.parse(result);`, it would actually give me something.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
String codeType = ResultParser.parseResult(result).getType().toString();
```

The `ResultParser` class will give you the type of QR Code's Result i.e.: URL, TEXT, MSG, etc.

You can use the below code to compare the types:

```
if(ResultParser.parseResult(result).getType() == ParsedResultType.ADDRESSBOOK) {
    // Implement your logic
}
```

Instead it is always appreciated id you use enum type rather than string i.e., use  `ParsedResultType.ADDRESSBOOK` instead of `String type = "addressbook"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to get the QR Code type:

```
String type = resultHandler.getResult().getType().toString();
```

This gives you the type of QR Code. For e.g. URI, TEL, SMS, etc.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

I would use a regular expression to test for the format. Depending on the type of strings you want to test, there should be plenty of examples online.
Here's more info on regular expressions: http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html
Java (Android) has builtin regex functions ("matcher" and "pattern")

Comment: I don't think you got the question. The question is: Would it be possible to extract the Type/Format of the QR Code? I do not care about what the strings actually return, I'm more concerned on being able to differentiate between the types of QR Codes (eg SMS, Text, Phone, URL)

Comment: I was assuming that you had read some documentation on qr codes. A QR code is a string, what you can get out of that string is what you put in. It does not have a standardized way of indicating whether a string is a url or a phone number or something else. However, you can add that information to the strings you put in the qr codes you create. If you scan codes that you have not created yourself, then the code has no info on the format. Also, you cannot prevent other people from creating qr codes that interfere with your codes, unless you use some type of hashing with a key that only you know.

Comment: Ah well there is a way to tell if a QR Code is a URL, Number, SMS, Text. I just need to find out how to get a Result straight from the intent. The `String result = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT")` method gives what is decoded from the QR Code, regardless of the format/type of the QR Code. The parse method on the other hand attempts to parse the result into a particular type of information (ie URL, Phone Number, etc).

Comment: Though that is a nice and very simple solution to stop people from going around the system.

Comment: And yes I'd love to think that there is a way in ZXing's Barcode Scanner that would tell us the difference between the Types of QR Codes since when you scan a QR Code using the App, it tell you the QR Code Type (Tel, Text, URL, SMS) as it gives the result.

Comment: You suggest that the format (url, phone, etc) is encoded in the QR code in a standardized way. I don't think it is.